# Why doesn't the sum of the values within a tooltip for percentage mode equal to 100 in NVD3 demo example?

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm looking at demo [example](http://nvd3.org/examples/stackedArea.html) for the stacked area chart provided by NVD3.js and it's not clear for me why doesn't the sum of the values within a tooltip in the 'expanded' (percentage) mode equal to 100?
[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug. It's still showing the original values instead of the percentages.

Comment: As far as I can see the tooltip simply shows the values from the right Y-axis at that point. Those also don't add up to 100, but are all scaled (I'm not really sure to what they're scaled btw).

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Yes, something's wrong with the [line](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/nv.d3.js#L14095) where they set up a display function based on the stack style. Have created an issue [here](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/641).